# Anaconda Navigator Linux instalacion

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, anaconda3

hoy intente instalar anaconda en kali linux, la instalacion creo que esta bien hecha  pero a la hora de iniciar anaconda-navigator me da este error:

```
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime-root'
No protocol specified
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display :0.0
Could not connect to any X display.
```

alguien Sabe a que se debe?

Muchas Gracias

Comment: ¿Estás intentando ejecutar `anaconda-navigator` con un usuario distinto al del entorno gráfico?¿Por un casual has instalado anaconda con sudo o con el usuario root?

Comment: instale anaconda con usuario root

Comment: @ChemaCortes a que te refieres con un usuario diferente al del entorno grafico

Comment: El servidor X lo estás arrancado con tu usuario, sin permisos para que ningún otro pueda acceder a él (ni siquiera root). Desinstala anaconda y vuélvelo a instalar como usuario normal, sin sudo.

Comment: ok lo instalo como usuario normal

Comment: @ChemaCortes si era eso  pero ahora me da este error: local variable 'DISTRO_NAME' referenced before assignment

Comment: se me queda el simbolo cargando poniendo loading applications

Comment: @ChemaCortes Gracias por la ayuda, ya lo he resuelto el primer problema es que lo habia creado en root y despues solo tenia que actualizar con conda update anaconda-navigator. Muchas Gracias

Comment: OK. Para que quede constancia, haz un breve resumen como respuesta y autoapruébatelo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este error puede deberse a que hayas instalado anaconda en modo raiz (root). ya que si lo instalas con root el servidor X lo esta arrancando con tu usuario sin permisos para que nigun otro pueda acceder a el (ni siquiera root), si quereis solucionarlo desinstalar anaconda y volverla a instalar pero en modo user.

si una vez instalada os da este error:

```
local variable 'DISTRO_NAME' referenced before assignment
```

y se os queda el simbolo de anaconda cargando, solo ejecutad este comando.

```
conda update anaconda-navigator
```

con esto ya deberia de funcionarles perfectamente :D